# Multiple copies of script in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-apps-script-editor, clasp

When I click on Tools -> Script Editor in a Google Doc, I am presented with the following screen, whereas before I would be directed straight to the script editor:

[image: multiple scripts]

I am worried that there are now two instances of my script. Is there a place I can easily see and manage the scripts and projects in Google Apps Script? I have checked out Google Cloud Platform Project through the script editor menu (Resources -> Cloud Platform project), but the resulting dashboard is not very intuitive to me.

As some background: I was trying to test Google Apps Script code deployment using Clasp and after the test, I wound up with the above issue. I don't know if the issue came about when I used Clasp commands or if it was when I copied the existing document before trying out Clasp.

Thank you for taking the time to read this. Any info is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind multiple script projects to a container (the container in this case being your document).

When you have multiple projects bound to a container and you open the script editor, you are provided with a menu with a list of your projects.

You can easily delete the duplicate project. Just select it, and then when you're in the Apps Script GUI editor, navigate to **`File > Delete Project`**.

Answer (score 0):

**G-Suite Developer Hub**

You can access all of your scripts at [G-Suite Developer Hub](https://script.google.com/home).  You can even monitor script performance from there.

**Same Named Scripts**

You will want to avoid scripts with the same name within a project but it's okay if they are in different projects.

**Backups**

If you want to make a backup of a project you can just copy it.  In the case of a container app you can make a copy of the container and you will be making a copy of the scripts it contains at the same time.